How do I download backed-up ISOs to PS3 directly (not PKGI)?
I followed these 2 tutorials to install custom firmware on my PS3, and it worked!






But now I am asking myself: Let's say I have a server at home where all the ISOs to my legally purchased games are backed up and I move somewhere else. If I wanted to download them, I would have to connect to my server with my PC, download them to my PC, then transfer to the PS3.
Is there any way to download the game directly to the PS3 or to set it as the target drive for the download?

Can you [edit] your question and clarify which tutorial you are referring to?

I'm not into the homebrew scene, but I'd guess the answer depends on whatever custom firmware you've installed. Maybe consider adding that information to your question?

Thanks @galacticninja I failed when trying to copy paste it, now its fixed
